# SWT Expand Bar not in the correct location when not expanded

Tags: java, swt

I have the following UI: 
[image: UI]

When it first loads the [`Shell`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell.html) it doesn't appear right underneath the find button despite it taking both columns in the layout. 
[image: Initial UI]

When the window has changed size it eventually appears in the right position. Like so: 
[image: How ui should look]

Here is the code for the Minimal Working Example:

```
package com.mycompany.swttest;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.DisposeListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;

public class BrowserTest {
    final Display display;
    final Shell shell;

    private Text f1, f2, f3,f4;
    private Label l1, l2, l3,l4; 
        private final ExpandItem resultDropdown; 
    private final Composite resultComposite; 
        Browser resultsBrowser;

    public BrowserTest() {
        display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display);


        //Listener to remove highlighting when this window closes

        this.shell.setText("Search");

        GridLayout thisLayout = new GridLayout(2, false);
        this.shell.setLayout(thisLayout);


        //SET MINIMUM WINDOW SIZES
        Rectangle screenBounds = this.shell.getDisplay().getBounds();
        Point size = new Point(screenBounds.width/2,screenBounds.height/2);

        this.shell.setMinimumSize(size);

        java.util.List<Label> labelList;
        java.util.List<Text> fieldList;
        java.util.List<String> textList;

        int thisStyle = (SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);

        GridData gd = new GridData();
        gd.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
        gd.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;


        l1 = new Label(this.shell, SWT.NULL);
        f1 = new Text(this.shell, thisStyle);
        f1.setLayoutData(gd);

        l2 = new Label(this.shell, SWT.NULL);
        f2 = new Text(this.shell, thisStyle);
        f2.setLayoutData(gd);

        l3 = new Label(this.shell, SWT.NULL);
        f3 = new Text(this.shell, thisStyle);
        f3.setLayoutData(gd);

        gd = new GridData();
        gd.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
        gd.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
        gd.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        gd.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;

        l4 = new Label(this.shell, SWT.NULL);
        f4 = new Text(this.shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER);
        gd.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
        f4.setLayoutData(gd);

        Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        comp.setLayoutData(gd);

        labelList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new Label[]{l1, l2, l3, l4}));
        fieldList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new Text[]{f1, f2, f3, f4}));
        textList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"F1: ", "F2: ", "F3: ", "F4: "}));

        //For every label/field, set text and layout
        for (int i = 0; i < labelList.size(); i++) {
            Label thisLabel = labelList.get(i);
            String thisText = textList.get(i);
            Text thisField = fieldList.get(i);

            thisLabel.setText(thisText);
        }


        Button findButton = new Button(this.shell, SWT.PUSH| SWT.CENTER);
        findButton.setText("Find");


        gd = new GridData();
        gd.horizontalAlignment = SWT.RIGHT;
        gd.verticalAlignment = SWT.TOP;
        gd.verticalSpan = 1;

        findButton.setLayoutData(gd);


        //New set of GridData for our results section
        gd = new GridData();
        gd.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
        gd.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
        gd.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        gd.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
        //gd.verticalSpan = 3;
        gd.horizontalSpan = 2;

        ExpandBar expandBar = new ExpandBar(this.shell, SWT.V_SCROLL);
        expandBar.setLayoutData(gd);

        resultDropdown = new ExpandItem(expandBar, SWT.NO_FOCUS);
        resultDropdown.setHeight(300);
        resultDropdown.setText("Results");

        resultComposite = new Composite(expandBar, SWT.NO_FOCUS);
        GridLayout gl = new GridLayout();
        gl.numColumns = 1;
        resultComposite.setLayout(gl);
        resultComposite.setLayoutData(gd);

        //Create a browser on a temp Composite
        resultsBrowser = new Browser(resultComposite, SWT.NONE);
        resultsBrowser.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));


        resultDropdown.setControl(resultComposite);
        resultDropdown.setExpanded(false);

         this.shell.pack();

    }

    public void open() {
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }

        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BrowserTest testBrowser = new BrowserTest();
        testBrowser.open();

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines:

```java
    Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    comp.setLayoutData(gd);
```

are adding a composite that you don't use but is using up the space in the center of the dialog. Remove this and it works OK for me.

If you want to use something to space the 'Find' button just use an empty label with the default layout data:

```
new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
```

Comment: This composite was used to fill the black space under the labels for the text fields. Removing it causes the button to be under the label which isn't the desired layout.

Comment: Well use a different GridData on it without grab excess vertical space

Comment: Added simplest way to space the Find button